# select not null column from 2 columns when select data from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I want choose the data for one column (`comment_graduate_id`, `comment_employer_id`) if isn't NULL. One of them will be NULL, and the second will have a value. So I want choose column with value to call its data from its table:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("
    SELECT 
    comments.comment_id,
    comments.comment_content,
    comments.comment_date_and_time,
    graduated.graduate_first_name,
    employers.employer_name
    FROM comments
    INNER JOIN graduated ON
    comments.comment_graduate_id = graduated.graduate_id 
    INNER JOIN employers ON 
    comments.comment_employer_id = employers.employer_id 
    WHERE
    comments.comment_job_offer_id = ? 
    ORDER BY comments.comment_id DESC");
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the answer you'd like to get for that sample? It would help make the question clearer

Comment: You can chain IsNull().  Somethign like IsNull(Field1, IsNull(Field2, Field3))

Comment: @Mureinik I want get the data for graduated or for employers , the one who hasn't null value

Answer (score 0):

There are functions available for this, I prefer to use `coalesce()` as it is not database specific and it can handle more then 2 parameters as well.

```
coalesce( comment_graduate_id, comment_employer_id )
```

This will return comment_graduate_id if not null, otherwise it will return comment_employer_id, if that second column is also null then you will get NULL returned.

The MySQL specific function for this is `IFNULL()` but I urge you to use coalesce instead.